# Read CSV with more than 10K lines and 36 columns

Tags: apex, csv

I need to efficiently read a large CSV file with approximately 10,000 lines and 36 columns. However, I'm encountering a 'regex too complex' error with my current implementation. Could you please suggest the best approach or provide guidance on how to read and store this data in a list in Salesforce Apex?

```
    public static List<Wrapper> parseCSV(Blob csvFileBody){
    List<Wrapper> newList = new List<Wrapper>();
    String contents = csvFileBody.toString();
    List<String> lines = contents.split('\n');
    if(lines != null && lines.size() > 0){
        Integer field = 0;
        for(String line : lines) {
            if(fields == 0){
                field++;
            }
            else{
                List<String> testValues = line.split(',');
                if(testValues != null && testValues.size() > 0){
                    Wrapper o = new Wrapper();
                    createwrapper(o, testValues);
                    newList.add(o);
                    System.debug('####o '+o);

                }
            }
        }
    }
    return newList;
}
```

Comment: This piece of code allowing me to read upto 1090 Lines

List<String> Linevalues= contents.split('\n');
        if(Linevalues != null && Linevalues.size() > 0){
            Integer Fields = 0;
            for(String line : Linevalues) {
                if(Fields == 0){
                    Fields++;
                }else{
                    List<String> fieldtest = line.split(',');
                    if(fieldtest != null && fieldtest.size() > 0){
                        //storing this values in list   
  }

and I am storing this list

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add that code that you currently have. Also, what error are you getting with that code? I wouldn't think that would be running into "regex too complex" (unless the error is happening on `contents.split('\n')`

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  Please [edit] your post to include your code and more detail - it is very difficult to read code in comments.

Comment: did you consider using OOTB [DataWeave](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/DataWeaveInApex.htm) to parse CSV?

Comment: @cropredy - posted my answer before I saw your comment, but figure the example can't hurt

Comment: @DerekF I think yes it could be because of that, but How can I overcome this, as I need to store this result in list?

Comment: @DavidCheng, Have added the example screenshot FYR

Comment: There shouldn't be any need to guess here. The error should tell you exactly what line the problem is. Again, you should add the exact error message to your question and also add a note of which line of your code it occurs on (the line number alone isn't going to help if we don't have the whole class). Also, screenshots of code are discouraged. They're less accessible and it forces people to type it all out manually if they want to demonstrate a small adjustment.

Comment: Post your code as text, not as screenshots.

Comment: @DavidCheng Done!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the new [DataWeave](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/DataWeaveInApex_UseCase.htm) capability in Apex? It does have the same CPU limits as normal apex, but can handle that type of complexity much more easily than having to parse the data line by line.
As you'll see in the first example, they can convert a CSV to Contacts with just a few lines of code:

```
%dw 2.0
input records application/csv
output application/apex
---
records map(record) -> {
 FirstName: record.first_name,
 LastName: record.last_name,
 Email: record.email
} as Object {class: "Contact"}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSV is not really a fixed standard, there are a lot of different dialects. Depending on the data it might not even be possible to do this with a regex, since fields with quoted text values might contain newlines, commas and quotes. If you want to do this correctly you will need an actual parser. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16952584/11935657) answer might be a good start, though I haven't tried that code myself.